# How to include a script that's outside the current folder in Julia?

Tags: julia

how can I include a script that's outside the current folder?
If the file is in the directory, I can simple run `include(filename.jl)`, but if the file is outside the current working directory, I don't know how to pass an absolute path to `include()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative pathes:

```
include("./filename.jl")   # same dir
include("../anotherFile.jl")   # one directory below
include("../../thirdFile.jl")   # two directories below
include("../folder/aFile.jl")   # one dir below, in folder 'folder'
include("./subfolder/yetAnotherFile.jl") # same folder, in subfolder
```